# how to delete rows in excel sheet using PHP

Tags: php, excel

Is it possible to delete rows in excel sheet using PHP ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Only works if your PHP is hosted under Windows.**

This should be a good start if [PHPExcel](http://www.phpexcel.net)* doesn't work.

---

Open

```
$this->excel = new COM("Excel.sheet") or $this->error("error");
$this->workbook = $this->excel->application->Workbooks->Open($path) or $this->error("error");
```

Close

```
$this->excel->application->ActiveWorkbook->Close("False");
unset($this->workbook);
unset($this->excel);
```

---

*I've never used PHPExcel, but it doesn't look bad

Comment: Excellent solution, but it's important to note that this code requires a Windows hosted PHP; it won't work on Linux/UNIX (Mac?).

Answer (score 2):

If it's Excel 2007 you can take a look at http://www.phpexcel.net